# Any conflicts with DLC from a Dutch PSN account when playing a UK PS3 version of South Park: Stick of Truth?

Tags: ps3, psn, region-lock, south-park-the-stick-of-truth

Unfortunately, here in the Netherlands we only have the censored version of South Park: The Stick of Truth for the PS3. Both the US and UK versions are uncensored. I am considering ordering the game from abroad, but I do not want to have any trouble with DLC later on.

So my question is whether I will encounter any regional conflicts with DLC purchased on a Dutch PSN account, while playing a UK version of the game.

**Background:**

> players who purchase DLC from a different region than that of their Game Disc will be unable to access their DLC from within the game

http://help.ea.com/en/article/ps3-dlc-region-locking-faq/

Comment: As far as I know, the UK version is cut too (as are all European versions). Usually, most DLC work with versions within Europe. E.g. I have a UK account and most German retail games I bought work with the UK DLC. If this was not the case, it said so on the PSN store on the DLC page where it says something like "This DLC only works with Disc L-9S8F3HG256K" and then you have to check if your disc has the same regional code. I can't say for sure if that's the case here though. In Germany, the PC version is uncut, so maybe it's the same in the Netherlands.

Comment: I found a Yahoo Q&A where it is stated that the console games in Europe are censored, however the PC game is uncensored. Too bad I want it for my PS3 :(

Comment: I'm sure that the UK PS3 version is still censored. It's only PC that's not.